# css selector to select first-child and then exclude grand-children?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Using CSS only, is it possible to take the following HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="level1">
        <div class="level2">
            <div class="select-me">should be blue</div>
            <div class="level3">
                <div class="select-me">NOT BLUE</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="select-me">NOT BLUE</div>
</div>
```

And select ONLY first element with class `select-me`? Using `:first-child`, the `.select-me` element under `.level3` is also selected (because, technically it is the first child as well). I want it to select one and then stop.

You can see what I'm talking about with this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/627q9kk7/1/).

I'm looking for a CSS selector, if it exists, to correctly highlight ONLY the very first `.select-me` element found. This selector cannot use any of the `level*` classes either, because those will always be dynamic.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is the very first `.select-me` element guaranteed to be the first child of its parent? If so, this makes things much easier. If not, then it's not possible with any number of CSS selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you can do this with a single selector but adding this to your jsfiddle should restore the default style for elements which you don't want to match:

```
.select-me ~ * .select-me:first-child {
    color: black;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```